# Quickbooks WebConnector require TLSv1.0?

Tags: quickbooks, pci-compliance

I have been running WebConnector for a year or more now without issues.  In order to meet new PCI Compliance standards I have had to upgrade my server to use TCIv1.1 or higher, eliminating TCIv1.0.  As soon as this went into effect my WebConnector stopped working giving me an SSL error.  My Server group is telling me that the SSL is fine and that the WebConnector requires TCIv1.0 in order to function.  I have found lots of documentation saying that WebConnector uses TCI but no version associated.

Can anyone confirm that?  And if so is there an upgrade that does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of QuickBooks WebConnector V2.2 is out and it supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 security protocols.

You can find more details at Intuit site here : https://developer.intuit.com/docs/quickbooks_web_connector

Note : you will require .Net 4.5.1, i.e. Windows 7 or later OS (that support .net 4.5.1)

Hope this helps !

- Anand

Comment: Hello Jessier, Did you get a chance to try out new QBWC with this security fix ?

Answer (score 0):

It has been confirmed that the current version of WebConnector only works on TCIv1.0.